# ActivityGroup with custom ListView

Tags: android

In my app, it has 4 tabs on the bottom, and each tab is connect to a ActivityGroup:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost
.newTabSpec("Group1")
.setIndicator("group1")
.setContent(new Intent(this, Group1.class)));
```

group1 just like a interface that control the behavior of sub Activity

```
this.history = new ArrayList<View>();
    group1 = this;

    /** a frame for its child **/
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(
            "Group1_Layer1",
            new Intent(Group1.this, costumeList.class)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
            .getDecorView();
    replaceView(view);
```

and goup1 has a custom ListView:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.xml, null);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell);
                            .
                            .
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

but it crashed, and the logCat shows:

`Unable to start activity,  java.lang.NullPointerException`

the crash just happened in custom ListViews,

other activities don't have this problem,

what's wrong with it?

Comment: Look closely to your logcat, it contains number of line where error is occured.

Comment: It happened when I press the tab, and logcat show source not found

Comment: It's not logcat. Under `java.lang.NullPointerException` should be full stack trace, and there should be number of line, where exception was thrown **exactly**.